# Params hash being interpreted as an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nested-forms, nested-attributes, parameters

I know the issue has to do with Rails trying to turn `[:street]` into an integer because it is treating `params([:address][:street])` as an array instead of as a hash.

Here is the full line that is throwing the error:

```
@address = Address.where(street: params([:address][:street])).first_or_create
```

This should be taking a nested input field `:address.street` from my form and search the table addresses for it. It works if I hard code in a string to search for, but not when I try to pass it a parameter from the form.

Suggestions?

**Edit:**

The line that is giving me the error has been updated and now reads:

```
@address = Address.where(street: params[:address][:street]).first_or_create
```

It now gives me: "undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass"

**Solved:**

I needed to add `[:client]` so the controller would know to find `[:address][:street]`.
The working line is:

```
@address = Address.where(street: params[:client][:address][:street]).first_or_create
```

It now will look up the street when creating the client, and if the street is there, it will pass back that id so I can assign it to the client's address_id field, or it will create a new street if it doesn't already exist and will pass back that id for me to use instead.

Comment: Have you tried `params[:address][:street]`?

Comment: Yes, that gives me "undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass"

Comment: `params([:address][:street])` is incorrect call if you are trying to get incoming params from form, you should use `params[:address][:street]` and investigate why you have nil for `params[:address]`

Comment: Can you post me your actual parameters that are being sent through? Clear the rails server terminal window with cmd+k, refresh this request and then post me the output from the server window

Comment: I didn't down vote anything but perhaps I should because your comment is insulting. There are a huge number of people who use Stack Overflow. Perhaps you should accuse them? I edited your question to make it easier to read, which helps increase people's attention to the question.

Comment: My apologies @theTinMan. I had checked it minutes before you edited it and it hadn't been voted down. Then I was notified you had edited it and it was voted down, so it was my mistaken assumption that you had done that for me not formatting everything properly. I was too quick to judgement, and for that, I have insulted you and embarrassed myself.

Comment: @MarcoPrins Here is the output:

Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"Bj5GB7W5GG54mcx+Ku0yaftDICPeXN1UTSs6L/ANrTA=", "client"=>{"first_name"=>"Chris", "address"=>{"street"=>"Maple"}}, "commit"=>"Create Client"}                                                                             
Unpermitted parameters: address

Comment: Solved it! I needed to add [:client] before [:address][:street] so that the controller would know where to look for address and then where to find street.